# How to compare string with chinese characters using regex expression in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a input string which may contain either only special characters or combination of special characters and alphabets or any other language text like chinese.

I want to check if string contains only special characters without any other language letters.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(200) ;
Scenario 1: SET @String='CHG5%#' 
Scenario 2: SET @String='%#$'     --> As it has only special characters, it should print false.
Scenario 3: SET @String='市汇聚%#'
Scenario 4: SET @String='市汇聚'


      IF(@String NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%')
        print 'False' --> String has only special characters without any other letters.
      ELSE
      print @String
```

Above code working for english letters but it is failing if string has chinese language text.

How can I include chinese language in above regex expression

Comment: Try `NOT LIKE N'%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'`.  Also tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide the code and text that you are working with so that we can possibly help you.

Comment: I'm using MS Sql server 2014. I have updated question with some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work to catch all Chinese characters, all basic Latin characters with no accents, and all western numerals. However, if I missed some, you can adjust it yourself - look at any Unicode table, and find the borders of the character blocks you want. Just like you can write `A-Z` to catch all characters from 65 to 90, you can also write `⺀-⿕` to catch all characters from 11904 to 12245. Ultimately it is up to you to decide what is a "special character". E.g. is Ⓐ ('CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A' (U+24B6)) a letter or a special character?

```
LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9⺀-⿕㐀-䶵一-俿]%';
```